# HANA join between tables with lowercase and uppercase data

Tags: hana

I have two tables A and B:

```
TABLE A
ATTR1  ATTR2  ATTR3
aa     xyz    zxy
bb     uuu    aaa

TABLE B
ATTR1  ATTR4  ATTR5
AA     zzz    xxx
BB     111    222
```

I'm joining them (in a graphical calculation view) using the attribute ATTR1 but I'm not getting any data in the output. I guess because the content is case sensitive.

I get around the issue by creating a projection of A, adding a calculated attribute ATTR1_UPCASE to convert the content to uppercase and then using this calculated attribute in the join in instead of ATTR1. I'm just not sure if this is the right approach.

Can someone give me a hint if this is right or if there is a better approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the right approach there. 
You have to "normalize" the values (in this case just making them both all uppercase or lowercase) so that they can be compared to one another.

One alternative option would be to enable case-insensitive search on session-level in SAP HANA (you have to set a context variable for that every time you want to run the query). That, however, will lead to the same usage of `UCASE` conversion function during the query execution as if you model it into your calculation view.

My recommendation is to keep this modeling in your calculation view since it makes this important part of the data design visible.

Ah... a third option would be to modify the tables by adding **calculated columns** that store the uppercase version of the columns automatically. This will, of course, increase memory requirements and required processing time when data is changed, but at query time the data will already be available in the normalized form. Whether this actually pays off or not needs to be checked by measuring the different implementation approached. It's probably a technique I'd only use if I cannot avoid it.

Comment: Is default collation used in HANA database case-sensitive?